# Generating tuple indices based on macro_rules! repetition expansion

Tags: rust, macros, tuples

Given a declarative `macro_rules!` macro that takes an arbitrary amount of arguments, how do I generate tuple indices based on a repetition expansion?

In the sample below, I'd like the `.0` on lines 6 and 7 to be generated.

- I've tried using an empty "replace" inner macro such as `(@replace $x:tt) => { $x; }`, but that doesn't work within a tuple construction.
- I realize I can just collapse the three statements into one, but in my actual macro I need the intermediate variables as well.
- I'm basically looking for an equivalent to C++'s [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

```rust
macro_rules! the_action {
    (@replace $x:tt) => {$x;};
    
    ($($queue:expr),+) => {
        let iters = ($($queue.iter()),+);
        let options = ($(iters.0.next())*);
        let values = ($(options.0.unwrap_or_default())*);
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 4];
    let b = [3, 2];
    let c = [5, -1];
    
    the_action!(a);
    the_action!(a, b);
    the_action!(a, b, c);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8fc3f25826f89237ebc447605a6f4a55)

---

*Bonus question*: given the lack of variadic generics in Rust, I expect this is a common thing to do in Rust. Why is there no built-in syntax for repetition indexing in macro_rules? The compiler surely has the info available. Has this ever been discussed in an RFC?

Edit: apparently [it has](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/28), but looks like it's been put on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another take, namely a macro `tpl_map` that applies an operation to each tuple element, yielding another tuple. It expects:

- A sequence of `expr`s (called `queue` to match your example) to determine the number of tuple components.
- An identifier `tpl` denoting the tuple whose elements are to be mapped.
- An identifier `fn` (which should refer to a macro accepting one argument) describing the tuple operation.
  I tried accepting a closure there, but that lead me to "type annotation required" errors, so I went with a macro.

As it is difficult (impossible?) to generate tuple indices in a declarative macro, it is currently constrained to tuples having at most 5 elements, but this can be extended by changing one single line (see `[(0) (1) (2) (3) (4)]`).

Moreover, I had to resort to the `apply` crutch (which - naively - should be inlineable) to make it compile.

```
macro_rules! apply {
    ($f:ident, $e:expr) => {$f!($e)}
}

macro_rules! tpl_map {
    (@, [], [$(($idx:tt))*], $tpl:ident, $fn:ident, ($($result:tt)*)) => {($($result)*)};
    (@, [$queue0:expr, $($queue:expr,)*], [($idx0:tt) $(($idx:tt))*], $tpl:ident, $fn:ident, ($($result:tt)*)) => {
        tpl_map!(@,
            [$($queue,)*],
            [$(($idx))*],
            $tpl,
            $fn,
            ($($result)* apply!($fn, ($tpl . $idx0)), )
        )
    };
    ([$($queue:expr,)*], $tpl:ident, $fn:ident) => {
        tpl_map!(@,
            [$($queue,)*],
            [(0) (1) (2) (3) (4)],
            $tpl,
            $fn,
            ()
        )
    }
}

macro_rules! the_action { ($($queue:expr,)+) => {
    let mut iters = ($($queue.iter(),)+);
    macro_rules! iter_next{($elem:expr) => {
        $elem .next()
    }}
    let options = tpl_map!([$($queue,)*], iters, iter_next);
    macro_rules! unwrap_or_default{($elem:expr) => {
        $elem .copied() .unwrap_or_default()
    }}
    let values = tpl_map!([$($queue,)*], options, unwrap_or_default);
}}

fn main() {
    let a = [1usize, 4];
    let b = [3u8, 2];
    let c = [true, false];
    
    the_action!(a, b, c,);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's some mind-bending stuff! Thank you for taking the time, gonna try and work with this :)

Moreover, I think this is a clear case for indexing in declarative macro's ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, generating them is not possible using declarative macros.

It depends on your use case, but as it stands, you could start out with the following, unpacking the tuples each time:

```
macro_rules! the_action {
    (@replace $x:tt) => {$x;};
    
    ($($queue:ident),+) => {
        let ($(mut $queue,)+) = ($($queue.iter().copied(),)+);
        let ($($queue,)+) = ($($queue.next(),)+);
        let values = ($($queue.unwrap_or_default(),)*);
        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 4];
    let b = [3, 2];
    let c = [5, -1];
    
    the_action!(a);
    the_action!(a, b);
    the_action!(a, b, c);
}
```

If you need to access the intermediate steps, you might pack them into different structs, as in:

```
macro_rules! the_action {
    (@replace $x:tt) => {$x;};
    
    ($($queue:ident),+) => {
        {
            struct Step1<$($queue,)+> {
                $($queue: $queue,)+
            }
            let mut step1 = Step1{$($queue: $queue.iter().copied(),)+};
            struct Step2<$($queue,)+> {
                $($queue: $queue,)+
            }
            let step2 = Step2{$($queue: step1.$queue.next(),)+};
            let values = ($(step2.$queue.unwrap_or_default(),)*);
        }    
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 4];
    let b = [3, 2];
    let c = [5, -1];
    
    the_action!(a);
    the_action!(a, b);
    the_action!(a, b, c);
}
```

One alternative would be to unpack the tuples into an array, and use indices - which would not even be needed to be created macro-wise.

Comment: Hmmm, never realized you could reuse the repetition var in such a way, shadowing the original names. It's unfortunately unworkable for me as I need access to the intermediate variables later on as well, nor can I use arrays because the types of a, b, and c are actually generic in my real code. :/

Nonetheless, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: @StijnFrishert Maybe you can circumvent the intermediate variable restriction by packing them into own structs (see updated answer).